# AWS dynamoDB executeStatement pagination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use PartiQL to query DynamoDB and paginate the result.

According to the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#executeStatement-property. The query result gives `lastEvaluatedKey`

The doc says `If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response, you need to paginate the result set.`

But the doc does not way how to paginate the result. `executeStatement` does not take `lastEvaluatedKey` as a parameter.

I want to use `Limit` to get 10 items at a time. Like 10 items, the next page get another 10 items.

Is this possible with `executeStatement`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `NextToken` to the `ExecuteStatement` as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html

Search for `NextToken` on the docs link you used in the question.

Please beware the limit applies BEFORE any filtering. There's no way to ask for 10 post-filtered items.